# Error CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET(C#) al momento de presionar una imagen que seria esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de presionarlo debería abrir un archivo de Word ya predefinido. Al correrlo dentro de ASP.NET funciona sin problema pero al publicarlo dentro de IIS, es la única falla que tiene ya que muestra el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudar a resolverlo por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta fue resuelta en este foro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322306/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-000209ff-0000-0000-c0

Te lo resumo:

Ejectuta `DCOMCNFG.exe`

```
Component Service -> 

Computers-> 

My Computer->

DCOM Config->
```

Revisa Microsoft Office Word y selecciona la Pestaña "Security"
En esta parte verás la opción de "Launch and Activation Permission"
Selecciona "Customize" y luego "edit"
Luego agrega los permisos a los usuarios que quieres darles acceso.

Nota: Mi Windows es en Inglés, pero los nombres de las opciones creo que las puedes entender.

Comment: Hola Hugo lo que pasa es que no viene Microsoft Office Word. ¿Alguna idea del porque?

Comment: Cual es la razón de utilizar un documento de Word? Por qué no utilizas un PDF?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que crea un word con todas las preguntas, por ejemplo si acerto al crear el word muestra de un color el radiobutton seleccionado y asi, aunque si me serviria mucho en pdf. ¿Tienes algun documento donde pueda hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Yo te recomendaría generar un PDF por varias razones, pero una de las principales es que no se pueden modificar tan fácilmente. Tal vez te sirva este artículo https://codeburst.io/generate-pdf-invoices-with-javascript-c8dbbfb56361

Comment: Muchas Gracias **Hugo**, opte por mostrarlo mejor en PDF y me resulto mas cómodo. Ya logre hacerlo.  Gracias